# Selection theorems for general measures (not probability necessarily)

Tags: probability-theory

I was wondering if anyone has any insight on this problem. Ideally, I would like to use a seletion theorem like Helly's reported below:

Suppose that a sequence of probability measures $\{P_n: n \in N\} $ on, say $M=R, $ is tight. Then there exists a subsequence $\{P_{n_k}: k \in N\} $ such that $P_{n_k} $ converges weakly to some limiting $P $ as $k \to \infty. $

My problem is that, while I have proved tightness and boundedness of a sequence of measures $\{\mu_n: n \in N\} $ (not probability measures in general), I would like to use the theorem above. I have seen a version of the result that fits my purposes (R. Cuppens, Decomposition of Multivariate Probabilities, Thm 2.6.1 page 29), but I would like to avoid having to use this result and rely on a more familiar setting like that of sequences of probability measures.

The idea is that since $\mu_n(R) > 0 $ I could always define a new sequence of (probability) measures such as $\{Q_n(dx):= \frac{\mu_n(dx)}{\mu_n(R)}; n \in N\}. $ But I am concerned that I am missing something in closing the argument and using Helly's selection theorem to prove that my sequence in terms of $\mu_n$'s also converges weakly to some limiting $\mu. $ I would like to see the formal steps required for such conclusion if anyone with better skills than mine could pass on their wisdom. Specifically, I am uncomfortable with carrying along the $\mu_n(R) $ in the denominator...

Any help is appreciated and I will thank in advance anyone for his or her kindness.

Maurice

Answer (score 2):

So $Q$ is a tight family, so there is a weak limit $Q_{n_k}\to \hat Q$, right? If you know that $\mu_k(R)$ has a positive limit, then you are done: just use the limit of a fraction is a fraction of limits. You know that for any continuous $f$ it holds that $\lim Q_k f = \hat Qf$ that is $\lim \mu_kf/\mu_k(R) = \hat Q f$. If $m = \lim \mu_k(R)$ then $\lim \mu_k f = (m\cdot \hat Q) f$.

Comment: Thank you Ilya. I have a further check that I would like to test with you. Is the fact that $\lim_k \mu_k(R) $ exists  based on the fact that my original sequence of measures is tight? This is probably where my issue started. In fact, I am aware that for probability measures, tightness implies the existence of a convergent subsequence to a limit, but for general measures?

Comment: @Maurice: you said you proved boundness, so $\mu_{n_k}(R)$ is a bounded sequence which has a convergent subsequence. Tightness by itself may not imply boundness. Imagine the case where $R$ is compact, and all measures are finite but $\mu_n(R) = n$.